# How to place two inputs inline without padding?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried this approach:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="input"><input type="text" name="seria" placeholder="Номер паспорта"></div></div>
<div class="col-md-8"><div class="input"><input type="text" name="organ" placeholder="Серия паспорта"><div class="error">Adı, Soyadı və Atanın adını daxil edin</div></div></div>
<div class="input"><input type="text" name="organ" placeholder="Орган выдавший паспорт">
</div>
</div>
```

But it gives me not desire paddings:

[image]

Exactly, I can reset padding for first element using `row` class, but I thing it is wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working fine for you now.

HTML :: 
 `

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="seria" placeholder="Номер паспорта" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="input"  name="organ" placeholder="Серия паспорта" />
      <div class="error">Adı, Soyadı və Atanın adını daxil edin</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="input"   name="organ" placeholder="Орган выдавший паспорт" />
   </div>
</div>
```

`

CSS ::

```
.input{
  width:100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: may be its conflicting with your main CSS. You can change the name of selector link ".form-input-box{ width: 100%; }" also editing my answer with output of this.